# An SoC pulling the power source voltage

Tags: batteries, capacitor, voltage-regulator

I'm trying to power a SoC with a battery as in the figure below. The SoC in question is the WeMos, based on the ESP-8226.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffNbZu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the WeMos is restarted, the following voltage is observed on VM1:

[image]

This poses a problem because the rest of the circuit depended on the voltage being a stable 3.7v. What is the correct approach for making the Vcc as independent as possible from the WeMos behavior?

*Tried solutions:*

I've tried putting different capacitors (10, 47, 220, 2200, 4700 microFarads) in parallel to the battery but they didn't fix the issue.

edit: The x axis in the diagram is in fact 3V and not 0V. The question is how to stop the power from the battery dropping below 3V.

Our board does have power and ground planes, and we were using an oscilloscope to measure the voltage at VM1. I checked the probe on the battery and recalibrated it to show 3.7V across the unconnected battery.

Comment: This looks quite odd. Can you provide a link to a datasheet or something? After a quick search I could not find much information.

Comment: @Vladimir Search for "WeMos d1" or "esp8266".

Comment: How did you measure the voltage?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. The problem is with the measurement.

Comment: Is the module specified for 3.7V?

Comment: @jimmyb my point is that basic info as the datasheet should be linked if you want good reception for a question. And I agree with Eugene, there is no way it is the SoC fault. Faulty power, faulty meas equipment or faulty setup. Plus I do not trust hand drawn unquoted charts.

Comment: Do you have any decoupling? Like .1uF ceramic caps right at each power pin of the SoC? If those spikes really are going negative, it means there is too much inductance between your battery and your chip (either that, or an uncalibrated scope probe). Does your board have power and ground planes?

Comment: What Mark said, move your capacitors to across the SoC IC pins instead.